# How to remove the box shadow from table?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ngtable

Got a query that I've been struggling with. I want to remove the shadow from my ng-tables when I hover over them, I was wondering how this is achieved:
http://prntscr.com/jcpl5g

```
widget-body {
background-color: #fbfbfb;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 0 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 0 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
box-shadow: 1px 0 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
padding: 12px; }
```

I've looked online for examples already but each time I've tried, it seems to remove the actual model but keep the shadow. Any help would be great!

Comment: Use `box-shadow:none;`

Comment: please show your code no picture

Comment: @AnmolSandal Thanks for the reply but did that before, it would remove the actual model but keep the shadow. Here: http://prntscr.com/jcppyr

Comment: That should not happen @JudgeDredd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How ever your question dosen't have any link of real example or code but from your question as you stated that on hover you get the shadow and you want to remove that shadow.

So simply use the firebug or any other developer tool and find the class or style which is applied during the hove from your CSS code it is not clear that 
`widget-body` is a class or id. I am assuming that `widget-body` is a class .
You also have to set the browser specific box-shadow code like `-webkit-box-shadow` and `-moz-box-shadow` to none;

In that class simply set the `box-shadow: none;` or you can simply remove the whole property called `box-shadow` as per your need and same for `-webkit-box-shadow` and `-moz-box-shadow`. Your final code look like this

```
.widget-body {
    background-color: #fbfbfb;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    padding: 12px; 
 }
```

**NOTE:** Kindly check that `.widget-body` class is not used by any other element in the website if that is the case then you have to create a new class and have to override the `.widget-body` class properties by `!important` keyword in that class otherwise shadow will disappear from website :)

You can also use the `:hover` pseudo-class

I hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks, you're explanation was fantastic. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Update css like this

```
.classname:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    }
```